# You must call Bugsnag.start before any other Bugsnag methods

Tags: bugsnag

In my application I'm experiencing a weird error with Bugsnag which I cannot reproduce but I see a lot in production.

I have a React-Native application with Native Modules.
In my `Applciation.oncreate` first thing I do is to call `Bugsnag.start`.
I also call `Bugsnag.start` in `index.js`.

In my Native Module's constructor I call for a method the eventually calls for  `Bugsnag.notify` this results in an error

```
You must call Bugsnag.start before any other Bugsnag methods.
```

Here's the stack trace of the crash:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call Bugsnag.start before any other Bugsnag methods
        at com.bugsnag.android.Bugsnag.getClient(Bugsnag.java:480)
        at com.bugsnag.android.Bugsnag.notify(Bugsnag:228)
        at com.yg.the.XXXXXX.utils.Logger.logger(Logger.java:56)
        at com.yg.the.XXXXXX.XXXXXXXReactNativeModule.<init>(XXXXXXXXReactNativeModule.java:116)
        at com.yg.the.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxReactNativePackage.createNativeModules(XXXXXXXReactNativePackage:17)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactPackageHelper.getNativeModuleIterator(ReactPackageHelper.java:42)
        at com.facebook.react.NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.java:42)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:1456)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackages(ReactInstanceManager.java:1427)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1338)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1200(ReactInstanceManager:136)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1108)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Since it's Native Module, it's initialized on a different thread but as far as I know Native Modules are initialized after `Application.onCreate` finished its execution. So I don't think this a race condition issue.

Besides, when looking at this error on Bugsnag console - in Breadcrumbs section I see a message stating - Bugsnag loaded and then Error occurred.

How can it be then, if it's possible that it's loaded but throws an error saying it's not started?